# Setting particle system to emit inside an object

Tags: modifiers, particles

I have a sphere with a particle system added to it: Add modifier - Particle system. In its preferences, I set it to Hair, with Render as Object (set to a cube object) and some other details like scale, rotation, etc.

As you can see below, this makes the cubes be distributed on the surface of the now transparent sphere. I would like to have the cubes emitted inside the sphere - not just below the surface, the sphere should be filled with cubes. Is this possible?

*Just in case this would be possible with another modifier/approach: I need to have randomized sizes and rotation of the cubes and need to have 1 or 2 thousand of them.*

[image: Particle system with objects emitted to its surface]

Comment: you can move the cube's origin so that it's on its top face

Comment: Yes, but that will only move them right below the surface. I need the sphrere to be filled with cubes. Edited the question.

Comment: Ah, probably my lack of knowledge. No reason for a particle system.

Comment: oh ok didn't understand your question, I guess @bstnhnsl gave the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the source of emission to „Volume“ instead of „Face/Verts“ in the particle settings:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks - exactly what I was looking for!